# Dynamic Select Dropdown Wordpress By advanced custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is my code for Multiple Dropdown.

I have two dropdown, One for City and other for Area.

So when someone select a city, then Area dropdown should automatically populate.

THis is the url

http://ctclick.com/category/

```
<?  

 $field_key = "field_570e68df39304"; 
 $field = get_field_object($field_key);


 if( $field == 'pune' )

    {  
        $field_key = "field_570e68df39304"; 
        $field = get_field_object($field_key);
            if( $field )
                {    
                    echo '<select name="city" class="form-control" id="city">';        
                    foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v )        
                        {
                            echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';        
                        }    
                            echo '</select>';
                }
    }

elseif ( $field == 'akola' )
    {
        $field_key = "field_570e691b39305"; 
        $field = get_field_object($field_key);
        if( $field )
            {    
                echo '<select name="city" class="form-control" id="city">';        
                    foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v )        
                        {            
                            echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';        
                        }    
                            echo '</select>';
            }   
    }
else
{
    ?>
    <select class="form-control">
    <option>Select Area</option>
    </select>
    <?
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Any your question is...?

Comment: Have a little respect for the users here trying to help you, and put some effort on reformating your code

Comment: I have re-formatted it... Please Check now

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will probably have to use some ajax in your code so that when you change the value of the first drop down menu, it triggers an ajax call. To achieve this you would have to include some javascript like this

```
$('#city_dropdown').change(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'get_city_areas',
            city_id: $(this).val(),            
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#area-dropdown').html(result)
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    })
});
```

What is happening there is that when your city drop down is changed, it triggers an Ajax request to get all related areas. Ajax in Wordpress is done through the admin-ajax system. You can read more on that here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

In your functions.php file you could add the following to register an Ajax call to retrieve the city areas

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_city_areas', 'handle_get_city_areas');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_city_areas', 'handle_get_city_areas');
/**
 * Handle the list of areas
 */
function handle_get_city_areas(){
    $city_id = $_POST['city_id'];
    //Using the city ID, retrieve the related areas
    //and then echo the new select menu
}
```

That should help you get what you are looking for.